# Change/Update frequency of Rate or Timer

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to update the frequency of the current running loops of a ros::Rate or ros::Timer object?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192013/change/update-frequency-of-rate-or-timer/) by [Johannes Jaegers](https://answers.ros.org/users/10981/johannes-jaegers/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2014-09-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A Rate object does not support changing it's frequency. Just make a new one. You can update the period on the Timer, just call setPeriod on it.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Johannes Jaegers](https://answers.ros.org/users/10981/johannes-jaegers/) on 2014-09-27**:
Thank you :-)!